# How to set Python path in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, python, python3

I know how to do the `export` to python path, but my problem is a little different. I have python 3.5 and I installed nltk using pip3. When I try to `import nltk.tokenize`, it works just fine:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk.tokenize
>>>
```

But when I run a file contains `import nltk.tokenize`, I get `ImportError: no module named nltk.tokenize`. I know I have to append the path such as `sys.path.append('path/to/nltk_data/')` Or `'export NLTK_DATA='/home/user/nltk_data'` But both did not work. How to fix this in Ubuntu 16.04!

**EDIT**

The path to nltk: `/home/ananya/nltk_data`

The path to my project: `/home/ananya/desktop/tenflow/model/research/im2txt/`

I am trying to build Tensorflow [Image caption as in this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/im2txt)

The command I am running is:
`bazel-bin/im2txt/download_and_preprocess_mscoco "${MSCOCO_DIR}"`

The command is to download the images, un-extract them, then run a python script that contains `import nltk.tokenizer` in the beginning **which is making this error:**

```
Saving to: ‘captions_train-val2014.zip’

captions_train-val2014.zip      100%[======================================================>]  18.76M  4.92MB/s    in 4.1s    

2018-07-15 18:44:44 (4.59 MB/s) - ‘captions_train-val2014.zip’ saved [19673183/19673183]

Unzipping captions_train-val2014.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ananya/Desktop/first/models/research/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/download_and_preprocess_mscoco.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/data/build_mscoco_data.py", line 98, in <module>
    import nltk.tokenize
ImportError: No module named nltk.tokenize
```

I have python 2.7 and 3.5 only, I do not have 3.6

**The beginning of the python script after the comments:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import Counter
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os.path
import random
import sys
import threading

import nltk.tokenize
import numpy as np
from six.moves import xrange
import tensorflow as tf

tf.flags.DEFINE_string("train_image_dir", "/tmp/train2014/",
                       "Training image directory.")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("val_image_dir", "/tmp/val2014",
                       "Validation image directory.")
```

Comment: Hello ananya and welcome to askubuntu! Please post the**file**. is it a pyhton she-bang script, ...?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example script, and an example command you use to call the script.

Comment: Thank you so much @abu_bua I was not sure what exactly you need but I did my best. Please let me know if that helped!

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you so much. I edited my question.

Comment: Thank you all. It turned out that the file is running using Python3 but it is calling another file that runs based on python 2 and I did not have nltk on Python 2.

Comment: @ananya OK, glad you figured it out! Please post an answer. (Yes, you can answer your own question.)